# Nginx and node.js routes issue

Tags: node.js, api, nginx

I've setup nginx for serving my node web app (api + web) but as I see the server is only responding to "/" (web root) calls.
When I test it I see the main web page (located at /index.html) but with no images or css styles and also the api which is in route /api/v1/.... (/api/v1/users, /api/v1/cars and so on) can't be reached because nginx is responding "not found".

Current nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost www.mydomain.com mydomain.com

    access_log off;
    error_log off;

    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

How can I configure nginx in order to serve all routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match all routes, drop the `=` sign. Directives with the `=` prefix will match queries exactly. More information can be found [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location).

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Here's the samples from the documentation:

```
location  = / {
  # matches the query / only.
  [ configuration A ] 
}
location  / {
  # matches any query, since all queries begin with /, but regular
  # expressions and any longer conventional blocks will be
  # matched first.
  [ configuration B ] 
}
```

Comment: Saved my day! Spent hours figuring out this issue....Thanks!